# How does script loading work when it adds scripts to code that already has been executed?

Tags: javascript, html, requirejs, amd, dynamic-script-loading

I'm trying to wrap my mind around script loading from this [website](http://requirejs.org/docs/why.html) but don't understand the part about how appending a child to the head for the script will make a script accessible on demand. The browser can't read the code backwards, so what's the point of adding a script to the head tag when the browser has already read through and evaluated that code already? Sorry if I'm using the wrong terms, but my understanding of the browser is that it reads through the html line by link from top to bottom so it doesn't make sense for something on the bottom (in the body tag) to add something above it (in the head tag) for it to be executed when it's already pass that area.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Example</title>
        <!-- script is added here but this part of the page has already been read by the browser already so how can it make a difference? -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // need something from www.url.com so create script on demand
            var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
            script = document.createElement('script');
            script.src = www.url.com;
            head.appendChild(script);
            // use the thing I just got from www.url.com
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The script will run when you append it to the DOM.

Comment: When `script` is appended in `DOM`, it is interpreted and executed..

Comment: This technique is commonly used when you for example load new stuff using AJAX, where the new markup, i.e. a form, need additional scripts which you don't want to load unless really needed

Comment: @Rayon 's answer is the correct one, and the spec is [here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#scripting-3) although if you can figure out how the spec defines how to load script elements after it's parsed past the `head` you're a better reader than I am. The consensus on the web seems to be "script tags added to the head after the head is processed are loaded without blocking DOM paints" but I can't personally find any specifications regarding that.